# Shortcode to appear and show the date not code in Title and description of Social Media sites

Tags: shortcode, title

I have used some shortcodes for my few posts. You can see [here](https://www.wtechni.com/dainik-bhaskar-daily-quiz-answers-today/) on of the post I have included the shortcode. But when I am sharing this code to any social media it is not able to show the date. Right now I am using these codes you see below here.

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_title', 'do_shortcode' ); // activate shortcode in Yoast Title
add_filter( 'wpseo_metadesc', 'do_shortcode' ); // activate shortcode in Yoast Meta Description
add_filter( 'the_title', 'do_shortcode' ); // activate shortcode in WP Title
add_filter( 'og:title', 'do_shortcode' ); // activate shortcode in Yoast Title
add_filter( 'og:description', 'do_shortcode' ); // activate shortcode in Yoast Meta Description
// [todayfull]  
function todayfullday(){  
return date('l jS F Y');  
}  
add_shortcode('todayfullday', 'displaydate');  
// end date
```

In wrdpress there is no problem with this code and I can see the code working in search results too but the problem is there when I am sharing this post to social media sites.

Answer (score 0):

in your function add_shortcode(,),
the right way to do it is :

```
add_shortcode('displaydate','todayfullday ');
```

the name of the shortcode first , then the name of the callback function.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/